# RegExp to return decimal number with optional 2-4 decimal dights

Tags: regex

> I have to develop a regExp which matches number as
>   following: 
>       *.0000 -> *.00 
>       *.1234  -> *.1234
>       *.1200  -> *.12
>       *.1230  -> *.123

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
\.\d{2}(0[1-9]|[1-9]{1,2})?
```

starts with a dot and 2 digits `\.\d{2}`

then an optional 0 followed by a digit `0[1-9]`
OR one or two non-zero digits `[1-9]{1,2}`

Matches your examples correctly.

If you want digits in front (your question states decimal number) you could add `\d*` in front of the `\.`... if you need anything more specific you'll have to clarify your question.